# Oracle JDBC: How to know which row throws unique key constraint?

Tags: java, sql, oracle, jdbc

I have an oracle query which i am trying to execute using jdbc. Following is the query.

```
insert into bd_vehicles_temp select * from bd_vehicles_temp_1
```

table bd_vehicles_temp_1 contains about 7000-10000 rows. If a primary key in bd_vehicles_temp_1 is already present in bd_vehicles_temp i get an SQLException : Unique key constraint.

the line of exception is offcourse `pstmt.executeUpdate()` in my code. Is there a way to pinpoint the row in bd_vehicles_temp_1 which causes exception.

Or do i have to do loop through rows in bd_vehicles_temp_1 and insert each row one by one ?

Thanks in Advance !

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you know the column that can cause the exception you can use (Oracle specific)

```
SELECT col FROM bd_vehicles_temp
INTERSECT
SELECT col FROM bd_vehicles_temp_1;
```

to identify all rows that are in both tables.

Comment: Its not about the columns. i am more concerned with which row caused the error.

Comment: How do i make intersect? I have less knowledge of database query. I am a front end developer

Comment: And i want to achieve this using code. No manual intuition involved !

Comment: And i already know the column which will cause this. There is only one such column.

Comment: Rewrote answer to reflect the comments and deleted the comments.

Answer (score 7):

The only way (I know of) to find out which row causes the problem is to use Oracle's "log errors into" feature. That way the `insert` won't throw an exception and any row violating any constraint will be written into the error table specified.

To do that you first need to create a log table that holds the rejected rows:

```
EXECUTE DBMS_ERRLOG.CREATE_ERROR_LOG('BD_VEHICLES_TEMP');
```

That will create a table named `ERR$_BD_VEHICLES_TEMP`

Then run change your statement to this:

```
insert into bd_vehicles_temp 
select * 
from bd_vehicles_temp_1
LOG ERRORS REJECT LIMIT UNLIMITED;
```

The statement will continue even if a row fails to validate the constraints. After the statement is finished you can check the contents of the table `ERR$_BD_VEHICLES_TEMP` for the rows that violated a constraint including the error message and the values.

(Edit): If you want to stop at the first error (and see that in the log table), then leave out the `REJECT LIMIT UNLIMITED` clause.

More details are in the manual:

- for DBMS_ERRLOG http://docs.oracle.com/cd/B28359_01/appdev.111/b28419/d_errlog.htm#CEGBBABI
- for the LOG ERRORS INTO clause: http://docs.oracle.com/cd/B28359_01/server.111/b28286/statements_9014.htm#BGBEIACB

Comment: These things are provided to me by oracle. How can i use the same using jdbc.

Comment: It might be worth noting that REJECT LIMIT UNLIMITED will result in partial INSERTs. @AbishekSingh: To avoid that, you can simply omit the REJECT LIMIT UNLIMITED clause.

Comment: @AbhishekSingh: just run the INSERT as shown trough JDBC. The creation of the error table can be done with SQL*Plus as that only needs to be done once (but of course you can call the procedure through JDBC as well).

Comment: @FrankSchmitt: maybe I misunderstood something, but isn't that the goal? Get all the correct rows into the target table, and not insert the faulty ones? (Thanks for correcting the copy & paste error btw)

Comment: @a_horse_with_no_name For me, it's not 100% clear from the question whether the OP wants to get all correct rows into the target table or whether he wants to completely abandon the INSERT in case of an error, so I just wanted to point out the alternative.

Comment: If they want to know which rows caused the failure, but want it to succeed only if all rows are successful, they could check the error table, report the rows that failed, then ROLLBACK.

Answer (score 2):

You are trying to insert into a table right? You should be using `pstmt.executeUpdate()` instead of `pstmt.execute()`. If there are already existing records in your table, then its better to delete all rows and add again if this statement is executed more than once.

Comment: Edited to make changes

Comment: bd_vehicles_temp contains more than 20,000 records. bd_vehicles_temp_1 contains about 7000 records. I want to append records from bd_vehicles_temp_1 to bd_vehicles_temp to make it contain 27,000 records

Comment: Use `intersect` to check which are the common rows. Then add the remaining rows into `bd_vehicles_temp`. http://www.techonthenet.com/sql/intersect.php, http://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms188055.aspx